# Get website name as displayed on a browser tab?

Tags: java, web

How can I get the String representation of what is displayed on a tab when opening a website in a browser? Let's say, if I opened `http://www.stackoverflow.com`, is it possible to extract "Stack Overflow" String, as it's shown here:

[image: Stack Overflow tab]

I'm interested in Java implementation - `java.net.URL` doesn't seem to have a method for that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24237036/how-to-get-name-of-website-from-any-string-url also maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919476/how-to-take-title-text-from-any-web-page-in-java also maybe http://www.gotoquiz.com/web-coding/programming/java-programming/how-to-extract-titles-from-web-pages-in-java/

Answer (score 4):

> I'm interested in Java implementation - `java.net.URL` doesn't seem to have a method for that.

`java.net.URL` won't do it, no, you need an HTML parser like JSoup. Then you just take the content of the `title` tag in the `head`.

E.g., assuming you have a URL:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Element titleElement = doc.select("head title").first(); // Or just "title", it's always supposed to be in the head
String title = titleElement == null ? null : titleElement.text();
```

Comment: You don't "need" an HTML parser. It's easier to use one, but it is not needed. It always frustrates me when the answer for something is "implement an entire suite of tools to handle one simple task"

Comment: Good answer, you could improve it with an example.

Comment: @user1274820: You *do* need an HTML parser. You [cannot reliably parse HTML without one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/157247). Now, it can be a very simple one targeted only at extracting this information, or a powerful general-purpose one like JSoup. But you need a parser of some kind.

Comment: Okay, any code you write to perform this task is technically a parser - what I mean is that you do not need an entire html parsing library to do get one piece of information.

Comment: @user1274820: I've tried to go down that path. "Oh, I don't really need a parser for this, I can just..." It's a massive waste of time. Barring a **really** good reason (like, embedded systems and not having room), it's better to just use the right tool for the job.

Comment: @user1274820: See my comment on it for why we parse. :-) But hey, yes, that kind of thing can be a 97% solution, no question.

Comment: Thank you T.J. That was my only point - it is not impossible to do with the standard library. I dislike seeing someone say that it is not possible - easier using a suite, yes, but I prefer code that I can tweak as needed to software libraries that rely on their creators to update and bugfix.

Answer (score 0):

Look for following pattern in reponse -

```
private static final Pattern TITLE_TAG = Pattern.compile("\\<title>(.*)\\</title>", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE|Pattern.DOTALL);
```

One more solution as parsing HTML using regex is not considered good -

```
javax.swing.text.html.HTMLDocument

URL url = new URL('http://yourwebsitehere.com');
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

HTMLEditorKit htmlKit = new HTMLEditorKit();
HTMLDocument htmlDoc = (HTMLDocument) htmlKit.createDefaultDocument();
String title = (String) htmlDoc.getProperty(HTMLDocument.TitleProperty);
System.out.println('HTMLDocument Title: ' + title);
```

Comment: [Don't parse HTML with regular expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/157247). Just don't. Consider: `<!-- Old title: <title>This is the wrong title</title> --><title>This is the right title</title>` :-)

Comment: go it.. Adding one more solution I found on web.